# Excel VBA Code to input values into rectangles

Tags: vba, excel, rectangles

Develop a VBA to create the values into the three rectangles and determine the intersection of the numbers.

Example code for creating code.

```
Public Sub call_shareRectangles()
Call shareRectangles("inputRange", "C1")
End Sub
Private Sub shareRectangles(referenceRange As String, initCell As String)
Dim R As Range
Dim rangeIterator As Integer
Dim countRange As Integer
Dim move As Integer
Set R = Names(referenceRange).RefersToRange
rangeIterator = 1
countRange = Range(referenceRange).Count

move = 0
While (rangeIterator <= countRange)
For i = 1 To R(rangeIterator)
For j = 1 To R(rangeIterator)
Range(initCell).Offset(move + i - 1, j - 1) = R(rangeIterator)
Next j
Next i
move = move + R(rangeIterator)
rangeIterator = rangeIterator + 1

Wend

End Sub
```

Solution rectangles needed

[image]

Comment: Do you actually ask to do your homework for you ?

Comment: Why are there `2`'s in the lower-left portion of the blue rectangle? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Yes, I cannot figure out this example problem at all.

Comment: Well, that's between you and whoever gave you that homework. Come back when you have a well-defined problem and a question specifically about programming.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
    Dim c As Range
    With Range("B2:G7")
        .BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium, Color:=rgbCoral
        For Each c In .Cells: c.value = c.value + 1:  Next
    End With
    With Range("C4:E12")
        .BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium, Color:=rgbDarkViolet
        For Each c In .Cells: c.value = c.value + 1:  Next
    End With
    With Range("D3:I10")
        .BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium, Color:=rgbGray
        For Each c In .Cells: c.value = c.value + 1:  Next
    End With
```

will produce this result:

[image]